# Como puedo saber cuantos elementos hay en un array typescript

Tags: javascript, web

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en angular y tengo un array de este estilo

```
[
 {id: 1, title: 'lorem', amount: 1},
 {id: 1, title: 'ipsum', amount: 3},
 {id: 1, title: 'lorem', amount: 2}
]
```

Como puedo saber cuantos elementos totales tengo teniendo en cuenta la key amount de cada elemento, **en el caso del ejemplo serian 6 elementos en total, sumando todos los amount**

Comment: Y qué has intentado o investigado al respecto?

Comment: Con [**`reduce()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) lo obtendrías, saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) es una función de bucle que tiene como objetivo "acumular" un resultado final.

```
reduce( [función a ejecutar para cada iteración], [valor inicial] )
```

```js
const array = [
 {id: 1, title: 'lorem', amount: 1},
 {id: 1, title: 'ipsum', amount: 3},
 {id: 1, title: 'lorem', amount: 2}
]

const res = array.reduce((acumulador, actual) => acumulador += actual.amount, 0)
console.log(res)

// la lógica es similar a
let res2 = 0
for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++){
  res2 += array[i].amount
}
console.log(res2)
```